# Bind ng-options to remote JSON data?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'd like to bind select options to a remote data source while skipping the need for an intermediate field. I'm not sure this is possible.

For example, my ideal HTML would be:

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-options="obj for obj in getCities(state).data"></select>
```

The call to my scope's getCities takes the state value (bound elsewhere on the model) and makes a remote call using $http.get to get the list of cities.

In my scenario, there would be multiple selects managed by the same controller and thus there isn't a single place to store each set of data returned, nor would I know exactly when to perform the query.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this. I can't just return an $http promise from getCities because it is then called repeatedly.

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of HTTP calls, you cannot do this.  And just as you wouldn't know when to the perform the query, neither would Angular.  I'm not understanding why your controller's scope can't have multiple sets of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood what exactly you were asking in my comment above.  You can pull this off with a sort of late-binding approach.  Your `ngOption` should be looking at your model as normal, and your promise callback should modify your controller's scope.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XaC8e/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
    <select ng-model="state1" ng-options="s for s in states" ng-change="loadNewCities(state1);">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="city1" ng-options="c for c in cities[state1]">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="state2" ng-options="s for s in states" ng-change="loadNewCities(state2);">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="city2" ng-options="c for c in cities[state2]">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="state3" ng-options="s for s in states" ng-change="loadNewCities(state3);">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="city3" ng-options="c for c in cities[state3]">
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>


    1: {{city1}}, {{state1}}
    <br/>
    2: {{city2}}, {{state2}}
    <br/>
    3: {{city3}}, {{state3}}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.states = ['ca', 'ny', 'va'];
    $scope.cities = {
        'ca': ['san diego', 'san francisco']
    };

    $scope.loadNewCities = function (s) {
        if (typeof $scope.cities[s] !== 'undefined') {
            // don't load if we already have cities
            return;
        }
        // TODO call a service here, run the $scope.$apply in the callback
        if (s == 'ny') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // faking a callback
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.cities[s] = ['nyc', 'buffalo'];
                });
            }, 200);
        }
        if (s == 'va') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // faking a callback
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.cities[s] = ['richmond', 'chesapeake'];
                });
            }, 200);
        }
    };    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was having a child controller/scope to hold the values.