# Angular directive that needs remote data before it renders

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a `<select>` element where its `<option>` are populated from remote data.

It looks like my template is getting rendered before the ajax call finishes.

How can I make sure that my template does not render before I have fetched the data necessary for it?

```
myApp.directive('dynamicSelect', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      source: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, data, attrs){
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: scope.source.url
      }).done(function(response){
        scope.options = response.options;
      });
    },
    template: '<select><option ng-repeat="option in scope.options" value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.name }}</option></select>'
  }
});
```

Comment: Use ng-options instead. See the listed reference.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178553/1913396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it right. Use

- `ngOptions` directive to populate options.
- `$http` service to load data and automatically trigger digest update.
- consider adding `ngModel` to select.

The directive then will look:

```
myApp.directive('dynamicSelect', function($http) {
  return {
    scope: {
      source: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, data, attrs) {
      $http.get(scope.source.url).then(function(response) {
        scope.options = response.data.options;  
      });
    },
    template: '<select ' +
      'ng-model="selected" ' +
      'ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options"></select>'
  }
});
```

Comment: interesting - do you need to require the $http service?

Comment: Yes, you need to inject it into directive.

Comment: Thanks dfsq, still trying to get it to populate (right now it's still just showing empty select)

Comment: So I got it working with ng-repeat, but not ng-options. Does ng-options require a ng-model? I'm not clear on that from reading the ng-options docs.

Comment: Yes, ngOptions requires ngModel, without it it doesn't make sense. I would say you need it anyway, otherwise you can't get selected option to pass data further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive to hide the component until data is populated through ajax request.

```
template: '<select ' +
      'ng-model="selected"' +
      'ng-show="scope.options"'+
      'ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options"></select>'
```